# Routing issue when using URL.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

All,

I have the following route/action defined on my controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("widgets/download-functions")]

[Route("download/{publishedReportId}"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(int publishedReportId)
```

And inside my js code, I want to create some routing with the appropriate id.

This is what I have inside my js code (which doesn't work).  What am I missing?

```
self.downloadFile = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("@(Url.Action("Download", new { publishedReportId = 9999 }))");
    console.log("@(Url.Action("Download"))");
};
```

Still new to this stuff and learning, I am sure it is something simple.

When I run this code, I get the following in the console

**Console output**

[image]

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: What does not work with the code you have provided?  Saying its "not working" is not very helpful

Comment: @RyanCarlisle that still makes no sense.  Razor is never called from HTML, HTML is a markup language, it is non-functioning.  All Razor syntax is executed on the server to _generate_ HTML which has nothing to do with jQuery or Ajax.  I think you have some deep misunderstandings on what Razor is

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Url.Action, it doesn't take advantage of attribute routing, you will need to follow the original method of routing, which is to use, Action, Controller, area and params to get the extension method to produce the url.

```
[RoutePrefix("widgets/download-functions")]
public class WidgetDownloadController : Controller
```

...

```
[Route("download/{publishedReportId}"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(int publishedReportId)
```

You would get a Url.Action like:

```
console.log("@(Url.Action("Download","WidgetDownload", new { publishedReportId = 9999 }))");
```

Also, this will only work on scripts that are parsed by the razor engine, ie. scripts that are written directly in the view.

Comment: Ok, the above code is creating a link of '/widgets/download-functions?publishedReportId=9999'

I want to create a link of '/widgets/download-functions/9999'

How do I accomplish that?